# How to make a recursive call with a decreasing argument?

Tags: coq

```
Inductive bar {X : Type} : list X -> Prop :=
  | bar_nil : bar []
  | bar_fst : forall x l, bar (rev l ++ l) -> bar (rev l ++ [x] ++ l)
  | bar_snd : forall x l, bar (rev l ++ [x] ++ l) -> bar (rev l ++ [x; x] ++ l).

Axiom bar_surround :
  forall X x (l : list X),
  bar l -> bar ([x] ++ l ++ [x]).

Inductive list_last {X : Type} : list X -> Prop :=
  | ll_nil : list_last []
  | ll_snoc : forall l x, list_last l -> list_last (l ++ [x]).

Axiom ll_app :
  forall X (a b : list X),
  list_last a -> list_last b -> list_last (a ++ b).

Axiom ll_from_list :
  forall {X} (l : list X),
  list_last l.

Axiom app_head_eq :
  forall X (a b c : list X),
  a ++ c = b ++ c -> a = b.

Theorem foo :
  forall X (l: list X), l = rev l -> bar l.
Proof.
intros.
induction l.
- constructor.
- assert (Hll := ll_from_list l).
  inversion Hll.
  + apply (bar_fst x []). apply bar_nil.
  + rewrite <- H1 in H.
    simpl in H.
    rewrite rev_app_distr in H.
    rewrite <- app_assoc in H.
    simpl in H.
    inversion H.
    apply app_head_eq in H4.
    apply bar_surround.
```

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
x : X
l, l0 : list X
x0 : X
H : x :: l0 ++ [x0] = x0 :: rev l0 ++ [x]
IHl : l = rev l -> bar l
Hll : list_last l
H0 : list_last l0
H1 : l0 ++ [x0] = l
H3 : x = x0
H4 : l0 = rev l0
______________________________________(1/1)
bar l0
```

I am only a step away from getting this exercise solved, but I do not know how to do the induction step. Note that `IHl` is useless here and replacing induction on `l` with induction on `Hll` would have a similar problem. In both cases, the inductive hypothesis would expect a call with a one step decrease while I need two - one with the item taken from both the start and the end of the list on both sides of the equality.

Consider that the type of the function I am trying to prove is `forall X (l: list X), l = rev l -> bar l` and I have `l0 = rev l0 -> bar l0` in the goal here. `l0` is a decreased argument thereby making the recursive call safe.

What should I do here?

Comment: For this kind of question, it's better to first work out a proof with pen and paper, i.e., free from Coq's formalism, and only after that translate it in Coq. It's highly unlikely you'll figure this out purely in Coq, without the high-level understanding that would allow you to write a pen-and-paper proof in the first place. If you do have such a proof to show, we can tell you what is missing to translate it into Coq, or point out mistakes (although the latter would be more a math question).

Comment: You might have misunderstood. I've already proven all those axioms on my own side - in this post they are here purely for the benefit of those who want to run the last proof themselves. This problem is one of the SF book exercises so I've obfuscated it for that reason. Now that I've gotten this far, I could easily translate it into Idris and that would be it. There is just one missing step in it, namely how to do the actual induction without having access to recursion.

Comment: I was not talking about the axioms either. You are trying to prove that one characterization of palindromes implies another, and I don't think the problem is as trivial as "just one missing step", or that the proof would be any easier in Idris.

Comment: The proof is 99% there. Once again, note the `H4 : l0 = rev l0` in the premise and `bar l0` in the goal. If I could do a recursive call in a language like Idris, it would be done. My issue is that I do not know how to twist the induction tactic.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic I don't think you would be allowed to make the recursive call in Idris. It wouldn't know that `l0` is a subterm of `l` and would yell at you for potentially infinite recursion. So would Coq. Also, you can generally get Idris's "free-er" induction by using `Fixpoint` instead of `induction`, I think Idris is mostly nicer than Coq when you have a lot of complicated dependent matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the following inductive predicate:

```
Inductive delist {A : Type} : list A -> Prop :=
| delist_nil : delist []
| delist_one x : delist [x]
| delist_cons x y l : delist l -> delist (x :: l ++ [y])
.

Theorem all_delist {A} : forall xs : list A, delist xs.
```

Then in your final theorem, induction on `delist xs` will split into the cases you need.

---

Another solution is by strong induction on the length of the list:

```
Lemma foo_len X : forall (n : nat) (l: list X), length l <= n -> l = rev l -> bar l.
Proof.
  induction n.
  (* Nat.le_succ_r from the Arith module is useful here *)
  ...
Qed.

(* Final theorem *)
Theorem foo X : forall (l : list X), l = rev l -> bar l.
Proof.
  intros; apply foo_len; auto.
Qed.
```

This is a more common and systematic principle than `delist`, but you will need to work more than the ad-hoc inductive type above to use the induction hypothesis in the main proof.

Comment: Is what you suggest really the only option here? Is there no way to make the induction tactic do what I want in my own proof?

Comment: Does `delist` actually help? All it seems to do is boil down the issue @OP is having. That is, in my naive implementation of `all_delist`, I'm getting back to the same problem as in the question, except without the other gunk in the way.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Do you mean breaking `l` into `x :: l0 ++ [x0]` and then making a recursive call on `l0`? Does Idris really allow that? That would be surprising to me. How does Idris decide the termination of recursive functions?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I do not know as I am not that familiar with the language apart from reading the book by Brady, but whenever I am having trouble with induction in Coq, I mentally translate it into Idris. You definitely could make the recursive call using `l0 = rev l0` after stripping the sides, but I won't make any argument on whether its totality checker will recognize the validity of that. Informally, it definitely is though.

Comment: Well, Coq doesn't currently have a way to turn off totality checking. But if it did, you could use the `fix` tactic, or write a `Fixpoint` instead of a `Theorem` to do what you seem to have in mind.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I've tried to implement `all_delist` and I am getting caught up in the same problem I described in the opening post (just like @HTNW said.) Could you show me how it is done please?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Nevermind, I got it. Nevertheless, the question how to do this using straightforward induction is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to implement the first part of what was suggested in the other answer. I can confirm that with this, solving the exercise is quite simple. That having said, I am interested how to solve the above using straightforward induction. Having to implement `delist` and its functions is more complicated than I'd prefer.

```
Inductive delist {A : Type} : list A -> Prop :=
| delist_nil : delist []
| delist_one x : delist [x]
| delist_wrap x y l : delist l -> delist (x :: l ++ [y]).

Theorem delist_cons {A} :
  forall x (l : list A),
  delist l -> delist (x :: l).
Proof.
intros.
generalize dependent x.
induction H; intros.
- constructor.
- replace [x; x0] with (x :: [] ++ [x0]).
  2 : { reflexivity. }
  + apply delist_wrap with (l := []). constructor.
- replace (x0 :: x :: l ++ [y]) with (x0 :: (x :: l) ++ [y]).
  2 : { reflexivity. }
  constructor.
  apply IHdelist.
Qed.

Theorem delist_from_list {A} : 
  forall l : list A,
  delist l.
Proof.
induction l.
- constructor.
- assert (ll := ll_from_list l).
  destruct ll.
  + constructor.
  + apply delist_cons. assumption.
Qed.
```